# i want to return in single row in this query but it returns two row whats tha my mistake?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DI.item_type = 'in_list' AND DI.item_method = 'item_category' AND DC.condition_method ='condition_time'  THEN 'TimeDiscount' ELSE 0 END) AS TimeDiscount, (CASE WHEN DI.item_type = 'in_list'  AND DI.item_method = 'item_category' AND DC.condition_method ='condition_date'  THEN 'DateDiscount' ELSE 0 END) AS DateDiscount
 FROM srampos_discount_item_list DIL JOIN srampos_discount_items DI ON DI.id = DIL.discount_item_id JOIN srampos_discounts D ON D.id = DI.discount_id JOIN srampos_discount_conditions DC ON D.id = DC.discount_id WHERE DIL.item_id =1
```

Thanks 
sample records

```
 TimeDiscount   ||  DateDiscount    

  TimeDiscount  || 0
     0          || DateDiscount
```

i want to return  to remove 0 and merge in one row

please help me Ths...

Comment: Guys please help me, i have struggle with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a (fake) aggregation function eg: MAX()  (and should be better use  null instead of 0 )

```
 SELECT max(CASE
        WHEN DI.item_type = 'in_list' 
          AND DI.item_method = 'item_category' 
          AND DC.condition_method ='condition_time'  
        THEN 'TimeDiscount' 
      ELSE null END )AS TimeDiscount,
       max(CASE 
          WHEN DI.item_type = 'in_list'  
            AND DI.item_method = 'item_category' 
            AND DC.condition_method ='condition_date'  
          THEN 'DateDiscount' 
          ELSE null END) AS DateDiscount
  FROM srampos_discount_item_list DIL 
  JOIN srampos_discount_items DI ON DI.id = DIL.discount_item_id 
  JOIN srampos_discounts D ON D.id = DI.discount_id 
  JOIN srampos_discount_conditions DC ON D.id = DC.discount_id 
  WHERE DIL.item_id =1
```

Comment: what is " line from text remove" ?  .. what mean ??

Comment: why  .. removed  the accepted  answer mark  .. after  months??  and post an image as an answer ..  ?  , if you have a new question you should post a new question not .. post a new answer  ..seems nit fair to me

Comment: I am able to ask new Answer that y post like this!

Comment: I don't understand you comment  .. you want  ask an answer ?? or ask a question  .. ?  you have posted  an answer  not a question  and in this way  .. nobody besides me will be aware of this question of yours (or answer) .. if you need a new answer you have to publish a new and well documented question and do not change the acceptance of a (right) question after three months ( it's hard for someone to notice it)